# Decimal Floating Point to Binary Conversion

Tags: floating-point, binary, hex, decimal, ieee-754

For my computer architecture class I had to do the following simple exercise:

Convert the number -1,1 to IEEE 754 single-precision floating-point format and then convert the binary number to hexadecimal.

The solution to this exercise seems to be 0xbf8ccccd, but I have a problem understanding why the last digit of the hexadecimal number is d instead of c again.

The step I seem to be making the mistake in is when I try to convert the decimal part of the number -1.1 to binary. Specifically, I start by taking 0.1 and multiplying it by 2 and saving the integer part each time.

After a certain point I see that a certain pattern emerges. This pattern is 1100 and it occurs due to the fact that we start by 0.4 and after a couple multiplications end to 0.4 again.

Using this method I end up with the number, **0001100110011001100**.

According to online converters though and as seen through the result of the exercise, the correct binary representation of 0.1 is **0.0001100110011001101**.

Does anyone have any idea why the pattern gets broken at the very end, and where the mistake in my thinking process lies?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is 2/3 closer to 0.666 or to 0.667 ?

Comment: @prapin Oh I see! I thought that we did the multiplications till we filled all the space for 23 bits that corresponds to our single precision, but I didn't think that I would have to round the number. Is that something I will have to do in similar cases where I can't represent the number accurately? Either way, thank you so much for pointing out the obvious!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Convert the number -1,1 to IEEE 754 single-precision floating-point format.

This is not possible *exactly*. All [IEEE 754 single-precision floating-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) are some integer (up to 24 bits) times some power of 2.
-1.1 and 0.1 is not representable as such.

Two closest candidates to 0.1:

```
0.0999999940395355224609375 
0.100000001490116119384765625 <-- closer
```

---

> idea why the pattern gets broken at the very end, and where the mistake in my thinking process lies?

When OP attempted "I start by taking 0.1 and multiplying it by 2 and saving the integer part each time.", the mathematical resulting pattern would be:

```
0001100110011001100110011001100... without end.
```

Yet as *binary32* has 24 bits of significant precision, a *rounded* value is used

```
   123456789012345678901234
0001100110011001100110011001100...
rounds to 
000110011001100110011001101
```

Pattern is *broken* as a *rounded* value is used.